# Can't delete index due to transaction log full in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

When I try to delete the index with the following command:

```
DROP INDEX [ClusteredColumnStoreIndex-20180619-104559] ON [dbo].[Transactions]
```

I get this error:

> Msg 9002, Level 17, State 4, Line 4
>   The transaction log for database 'Metrics' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION'.

There disk that the database is on is also out of space at this point.

Can someone help me delete this index?

Comment: One way or another you need to sort out your transaction log. There are a zillion posts on SO and on google about solving that - when you sort out your transaction log you'll be able to drop your index

Comment: What's your database recovery model? If `FULL`, you might try temporarily changing it to `BULK_LOGGED`.  Note that when you drop a CCI, you are converting the table to a heap and that will require much more space in the database than the columnstore.

Comment: run something like `sp_who2` and see if there are any hung transactions open that might be chewing up transaction log space

Comment: Stop worrying about the index. You have another issue. Back up the transaction log to another disc so that space is freed up. If it’s in simple recovery mode you have a large transaction running. You may need to kill it but the roll back will take log space as well. Add space for now until you get that under control

Comment: If your DB is running simple logging, just shrink your log files and then drop the index

Answer (score -1):

use below techiniques

1) Make sure the transaction log has been backed up and truncated before running large-scale index operations online, and that the log has sufficient space to store the projected index and user transactions.

2) Consider setting the SORT_IN_TEMPDB option to ON for the index operation. This separates the index transactions from the concurrent user transactions. The index transactions will be stored in the tempdb transaction log, and the concurrent user transactions will be stored in the transaction log of the user database. This allows for the transaction log of the user database to be truncated during the index operation if it is required. Additionally, if the tempdb log is not on the same disk as the user database log, the two logs are not competing for the same disk space.

Note

Verify that the tempdb database and transaction log have sufficient disk space to handle the index operation. The tempdb transaction log cannot be truncated until the index operation is completed.

3) Use a database recovery model that allows for minimal logging of the index operation. This may reduce the size of the log and prevent the log from filling the log space.

4) Do not run the online index operation in an explicit transaction. The log will not be truncated until the explicit transaction ends.

Comment: Providing generic "log minimization" suggestions does not help OP - who has a much bigger problem to solve. And setting SORT_IN_TEMPDB does nothing to help with dropping an index.